# How can I re-initialize (only) partial of data values in vue?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I know that we can re-initialize the data like this:

```
function initialData() {
    return {
        is_active: true,
        is_collapsed: true,
        resetable_data: 'value',
        resetable_stat: 4
    }
}

export default {
...
data() {
    return {
        initialData()
    }
},
...
```

But I am wondering how we can re-initialize only a portion of the data. I mean something like:

```
function initialData() {
    return {
        resetable_data: 'value',
        resetable_stat: 4
    }
}

export default {
...
data() {
    return {
        is_active: true,
        is_collapsed: true,
        initialData()
    }
},
...
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is your syntax correct? Is `data: { return {` correct? Isn't it `data: function () {
    return {`?

Comment: yep you are right @acdcjunior , it is actually `...data(){...` will fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
function initialData() {
    return {
        resetable_data: 'value',
        resetable_stat: 4
    }
}

export default {
...
data() {
    return Object.assign(
        {
            is_active: true,
            is_collapsed: true,
        },
        initialData()
    );
},
...
```

[`Object.assign(target, ...sources)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) copies the properties of the `...sources` (in this case, the object returned by `initialData()`) into the `target` (in this case the object with `is_active` and `is_collapsed`), **returning the `target` object**.